# issue with media queries css

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a problem with media queries in my css, i want to apply a style when the screen size is 900px, but that style works until the screen size is 810px.

this is my viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

and this is my css:

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px){
    .form{display:none;}
}
```

my html is only this

```
<div class="form"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
```

I couldn't find a solution about this problem.
Thanks for your help :).

Comment: can you upload it ? to see if it works for us ?

Comment: It's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kowbsLqm/ . You must have another style overriding it.

Comment: this is the link http://er-xc.com/test/test.html , I tested in safari, chrome and firefox and i have the same problem

Comment: Your problem isn't entirely clear to help you we need some clarification. You want to apply a style at 900px, and then a different style at 810px? Or do you want apply a style up to 810px, and a different one at 900px or larger?

Comment: @Bjack i want to apply at 900px, but the style that is in 900px querie only works until the screen size is 810px, if the screen is 900px nothing happen just when the screen is 810px i can see the change

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and all it was is that I had accidentally zoomed out my browser screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the below and let me know if it's work for you or not...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
        .form{display:none;}
    }
    *************
    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px){
        .form{display:none;}
    }
```

Also change the viewport line to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

OR

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```